# SQL Select Statement including SP Call has syntax error

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures, return-value

MYTABLE has ID column. However, following query generates syntax error.

```
SELECT ID FROM MYTABLE
WHERE ID = EXEC MY_SP ID
```

What do you think is wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't call stored procedures inline like this.

A couple of options include:
1) Execute the stored procedure and store the results in a temp table. Then use that temp table.
e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE #Example
(
ID INTEGER
)
INSERT #Example
EXECUTE My_SP

SELECT t.ID FROM MyTable t JOIN #Example e ON t.ID = e.ID
DROP TABLE #Example
```

2) convert the sproc to a user defined function which you CAN call inline
e.g.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.MyFunc()
    RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
(
    SELECT ID FROM SomeTable WHERE ....
)

SELECT t.ID FROM MyTable t JOIN dbo.MyFunc() f ON t.ID = f.ID
```

3) If the sproc returns a single ID, consider returning an OUTPUT parameter from the sproc instead and use like this:

```
DECLARE @ID INTEGER
EXECUTE MY_SP @ID OUTPUT

SELECT ID FROM MYTABLE
WHERE ID = @ID
```

Comment: Does this really simple need have such a complicated solution?

Comment: @user544433 - yes, you just can't call stored procedures inline like you are trying. Which solution you go for really depends on your exact scenario. e.g. you may not be able to use a User Defined Function depending on what your current sproc does (you can't do everything in a function that you can do in a sproc, but you can call functions inline)

Comment: I changed my sproc to UDF. But now I have another problem that:Only functions and extended stored procedures can be executed from within a function.   Which means, The sproc call that I made in UDF is illegal. So it collapses all my solution

Comment: There are certain things you can do in a sproc that you can't in a UDF (e.g. CREATE temp tables as one example). Hence my comment above about you may not be able to use a UDF depending exactly on what your sproc does. In which case, option 1) using a temp table would be the best candidate.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need the exec statement, just call the sp, exec is expected to be a separate statement

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do that at all.  Are you perhaps thinking of a User Defined Function rather than a stored Procedure.  Based on the context, you'll need a scalar UDF.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT ID FROM MYTABLE WHERE ID = @@SPID
```